# Powershell CSV ordered Export with specific columns

Tags: powershell, csv

i have following problem:

I have a query with Get-ADUser and have there specific fields to get (only test query)

```
$AllADUsers = get-aduser -Identity m.mustermann -Properties * | select mail, title, l, GivenName, Surname, company, department, mobile
```

Also i must add some static fields how language or comment in to the CSV, i take some variable for that:

```
$Language = "german"
$Comment = ""
$Link = ""
$gender = ""
$exportto = "C:\Temp\Export01.csv"
```

Than i want to export all entries in a ordered UTF8 CSV with Delimiter ":".
I do a foreach but always i get mistakes or not complete lists - i show you my code (but i have mistakes)

```
Foreach ($ADUser in $AllADUsers) {

  $MailAddress = $ADUser.mail
  $FullName = "$ADUser.GivenName" + "$ADUser.Surname"
  $Title = $AdUser.Title
  $Location = $ADUser.l
  $Comment = $Comment
  $Link = $Link
  $MobilePhone = $ADUser.mobile
  $Language = $Language
  $Divison = $ADUser.Department
  $GivenName = $ADUser.GivenName
  $Surname = $ADUser.Surname 


}

$ADUser | Export-CSV -Path $exportto -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ":" -Encoding UTF8
```

Can you help me?

The export must be with the ordered list and without "" and just in this order.

Thank you.
Max

Comment: Can you isolate the question to one issue instead mentioning you get mistakes? I think you're assigning the values to the variables, but you never use them. Quick tip: formula for FullName should be `"$($ADUser.GivenName) $($ADUser.Surname)"`

Comment: Sorry. Problem is, i got no export in my foreach. Also my values and variables are not in the export CSV. Whats wrong?

My export command in the loop don't work and the columns from the select are in the csv, not from my loop

Comment: Your query with the paramter `-Identity` can only return one single object. So you do not need a loop. Consider using calculated properties like @robdy's answer down here. ;-)

Comment: I know the parameter -Identity, this was just in my example, in my right query this is with more results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work, mainly because you are creating a series of variables that in the end you do not use.

To output to CSV, you need to collect **objects** with properties, not single variables.
A very elegant way is to create those objects using `[PsCustomObject]` syntax, where at the same time the order in which you set the properties make up for the order in the final output file.

Using the colon as delimiter character is unusual and may get you into trouble when other applications need to read and understand this, but that is up to you.

Another thing is that you mainly seem to use LDAP attribute names, where PowerShell has most of them mapped to more friendly attribute names (like 'City' which maps to LDAP 'l').

Your code revised:

```
# Get-ADUSer already returns these properties by default:
# DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName

# your hardcoded static variables:
$Language = "german"
$Comment  = ""
$Link     = ""
$gender   = ""
$exportto = "C:\Temp\Export01.csv"

# these are the extra properties you want to fetch
$userprops = 'EmailAddress','Title','Company','City','Department','MobilePhone'

# if you want this for all users, remove "-Identity 'm.mustermann'" and use "-Filter *" instead
$result = Get-ADUser -Identity 'm.mustermann' -Properties $userprops | ForEach-Object {
    # output an object to be collected in variable $result
    # the order in which you put them also determines the field order in the CSV
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        MailAddress = $_.EmailAddress
        FullName    = $_.DisplayName
        Title       = $_.Title
        Company     = $_.Company
        Location    = $_.City
        Comment     = $Comment      # static field
        Link        = $Link         # static field
        MobilePhone = $_.MobilePhone
        Language    = $Language     # static field
        Department  = $_.Department
        GivenName   = $_.GivenName
        Surname     = $_.Surname
    }
}

$result | Export-CSV -Path $exportto -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ":" -Encoding UTF8
```

**A note about `Export-Csv`:**

`Export-Csv` will always quote everything, be it a header or data field.

Simply trying to remove all quotes in a CSV file is risking mis-alignment in the field order and rendering the csv as unusable.
With PowerShell version 7 you have the option to use parameter `-UseQuotes AsNeeded`, but for older versions, you may safely do this using my function [ConvertTo-CsvNoQuotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60681762/9898643)

<sup>Since this code is all about **getting** AD information, I don't see why you would want to construct the FullName here. Just use the DisplayName property that is set in the AD as the code above does</sup>

Comment: I will try now import in my program (if it works) - i will answer again.

Comment: How i can convert the CSV without quotes with your function and stay encoding to UTF8? With the function i have problem that the special characters are broken ("ü", "ä" )...

Comment: @max95 Just use it like `$result | ConvertTo-CsvNoQuotes -Delimiter ":" | Set-Content -Path $exportto -Encoding UTF8`. The function itself does not alter the string encoding, which internally in PowerShell is Unicode (UTF16).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you really Theo. Now i want to remove headers at the $result command. How? -NoTypeInformation doesn't work? :/

Comment: @max95 The function also has a switch `-NoHeaders`, so just add that `ConvertTo-CsvNoQuotes -Delimiter ":" -NoHeaders`

Comment: Great! Really nice!

Comment: Problem: Encoding UTF8 makes UTF8-BOM not UTF8 :/ ?

Comment: @max95 For writing UTF8 without BOM, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63970205/9898643) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34969243/9898643) In this case, output the file like: `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($exportto, ($result | ConvertTo-CsvNoQuotes -Delimiter ":" -NoHeaders))`

Comment: Sorry, but now i get only 1 line export, not line by line

Comment: @max95 Oops.. meant `WriteAllLines`, not `WriteAllText`..

Comment: Perfect. Thank you Theo!

Answer (score 0):

There are some high-level issues in your code.

#### Incorrect assignment

In your code you should assign the values to specific properties of `$AdUser`. Something like:

```
foreach ($ADUser in $AllADUsers) {
  $ADUser.FullName = "$($ADUser.GivenName) $($ADUser.Surname)"
  $ADUser.Comment = $Comment
  $ADUser.Link = $Link
}
```

#### No export

Currently you export only last entry, you should pipe `$AllADUsers` to `Export-Csv`:

```
$AllADUsers| Export-CSV -Path $exportto -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ":" -Encoding UTF8
```

#### No use of Select-Object calculated properties

In general, you could have your code shorten to one-liner like:

```
$AllADUsers | Select-Object @{n="Comment";{$Comment}},@{n="FullName";e={"$($ADUser.GivenName) $($ADUser.Surname)"}} ... | Export-CSV ...
```

[Read more about calculated properties here](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/).